# looping thru array, increment doesnt work

Tags: c, arrays, loops, iteration, pre-increment

```
ARRAY_SIZE[10] = {0};
int i;
for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i ) {      
  printf("Before assignment %d\n", array_of_ints[i]);   
}
```

I was expecting the print out result be 0 thru 9, since `++i` increments `i`. And on the second loop it will print out 1, on the following 2, and so on. However, it prints out 0 ten times. Why is that? Thanks ahead.

Comment: `ARRAY_SIZE` is not the array size. Try 10...

Comment: You don't provide all code or your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you have is to minimal, it's not complete, and it's not verifiable.

Comment: and it does print out 0 to 9. if I add this two lines:    `//array_of_ints[i] = i;
  //printf("After assignment %d\n", array_of_ints[i]);`

Comment: First you have to provide minimal code so that one can compile and check. Regarding your code, you are printing `array_of_ints` and expecting result of `i`.

Comment: what should `ARRAY_SIZE[10] = {0};` mean? there is no `array_of_ints`defined. We are not clairvoyant.

Answer (score 0):

ARRAY_SIZE will not give you the length of the array. You have to enter it manually.

```
ARRAY_SIZE[10] = {0}; 
int i; for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) 
{        printf("Before assignment %d\n", array_of_ints[i]);    

}
```

Comment: Thanks. but still gives the same output. ten lines of 0.

Comment: Yes, because the array is initialized with 0.

Comment: Got it. i increments thru the index of the array not the value contained at that index. that is why!!

Comment: What is array_of_ints?